# Add value to WP Attachment Meta Data

Tags: wordpress, upload, orientation, attachment, aspect-ratio

I would like to let Wordpress calculate the aspect ratio & orientation when the media is uploaded instead of doing this in the templates. Then I can call images and ask for image.orientation which will give me 'portrait' or 'landscape' as a value.

Example, how it would look like after uploading an image:
[image: Example, how it would look like after uploading an image]

Is this possible or do I have to do this in the frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write some code for it. Use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata to get the width and the height, and then if $width/$height > 1 => landscape, otherwise its portrait. Store this value in the attachment using: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_attachment_metadata.

You can use an action for this, such as:

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'process_images');
```

Adding the solution as well, following from your code attempt (I HAVENT TESTED THIS):

```
function attachment_orientation_meta($id){
    $attachmentInfo = wp_get_attachment_metadata($id);
    $attachmentOrientation = ( $attachmentInfo['height'] > $attachmentInfo['width'] ) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';
    update_post_meta($id, 'orientation', $attachmentOrientation);
}
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'attachment_orientation_meta' );
```

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for your reply. I can't get it to work though. I re-uploaded some images but no effect. Is something missing?
`// add orientation to attachments
 function attachment_orientation_meta(){
  $attachmentInfo = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id ); 
   $attachmentOrientation = ( $attachmentInfo['height'] > $attachmentInfo['width'] ) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';
  $attachmentOrientationMeta =  wp_update_attachment_metadata( $post_id, $attachmentOrientation );
  return $attachmentOrientationMeta;
 }

 add_action( 'add_attachment', 'attachment_orientation_meta' );`

Comment: check the updated answer. Basically, the "add_attachment" action takes the attachment id as parameter. You have to use it in your functions then.. and finally, update_attachment_metadata needs an array as second parameter. I ahve used update_post_meta above, which is "easier".

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. Since yesterday I'm trying to make it work, but I can't get it to work unfortunately :(

Comment: So I tested it and your are right, the hook works as it detects the upload but it is "too soon" to read the metadata. I searched a little bit but couldnt find a later hook, so probably it doesnt exist. In that case, my approach would be: when you detect a new upload, trigger a cron job (http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/16/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/) to execute 1 min later, and code that cron job to fetch metadata, update attachment meta, etc..

Comment: Thanks for your approach. I will mark this as the solution.